# Facebook Comments Don't Show in Comment Moderation Tool (but show on the actual page)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

It seems like no comments after 26th of October appear in my Comment Moderation tool. Comments, however, appear on the page.

On the webpage, I can see comments after that (some of which are spam which I need to moderate).

I have the following code on page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=xxxxx';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="xxxxx.com" data-numposts="7" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

Both the fb:admins and fb:app_id properties are set and show up in Open Graph Debugger (I actually removed the fb:admins property since the admins are set in the moderation tool)

Comment: Same problem here, I put comments and I can't see them in the moderation panel..

Comment: @IdanShechter If I remember correctly, there was an issue with redirection (In my case, fb URL was `example.com/page/1/` but I wanted to display comments on `example.com/page/`. Note that I had a 301 redirect from  `example.com/page/1/` to `example.com/page/`.

Comment: I've checked, there is no redirect. I am using a URL with # (hash) for the pages, but I had no problem with it on other websites.

Comment: I get a moderation when I put the comment div inline. The problem for me is that I load it that I load the comment dynamically, parsing the page when a popup is open. I have no idea how to make moderation available for dynamically loaded comment plugin.

Comment: @IdanShechter If you wish, feel free to edit the question to add this information :)

Comment: thank, I opened a new question, found out that the hash is the issue, but I need it in order to load different comments in the same page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305283/facebook-moderation-link-doesnt-show-when-using-hash-in-data-href-url

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem when I realized the `og:url` and `data-href`, which were automatically generated, did not match the current URL.

- Current URL was **www.demo.com/es/page**
- `og:url` and `data-href` were **www.demo.com/page**

Facebook developer tool only gives a subtle notice about mismatch (Redirect Path) with `og:url`(og:url Meta Tag) and the current url (Input URL).