# Facebook moderation link doesn't show when using hash in data-href URL

Tags: javascript, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am using Facebook comments in my website.  My problem is that I don't get to see the moderation tool. I see it when the code is embedded within the page when it loads. In my case, I load the comment section dynamically, inserting the comment div into another div and running  `FB.XFBML.parse();`.

**Note: I am using hash in the URL for the data-href.**

I do see the Facebook comments plugin and I can write comments, but the moderation tool is not visible.

Any ideas how to make the moderation tool visible also when dynamically rendering Facebook comments plugin?

**Update:** I've also found out that the moderation link doesn't show up when I have the `data-href` in place, even if I embed the widget inline and load it when the page loads. I use a link that the code runs on and with App Id assigned correctly. I did scrapped the page using Facebook tool and found no issue.

This code doesn't show the moderation link:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://example.com/" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

**Update 2:** I removed the `data-href` from the dynamically inserted widget div and it still doesn't work.

**Update 3:** I removed the hash from the data-href URL in the inline code and it shows the moderation link with the data-href. Leads me to believe that the hash might cause an issue here.

**Update 4:** Moderation appears when dynamically loading the widget, but only when there is not hash in the URL. So the hash seems to be the issue. Need to ind way to solve this.

The problem with using a hash is that Facebook doesn't even recognize this Comments box as part of the one that is assigned to my website. I asked someone to post a link (which should be moderated) none of the comments, nor the one with the link appeared in the online moderation panel on Facebook.